# Grizzly Jersey suddenly asks for applicatonContext.xml

Tags: jersey, grizzly

In my existing app this code works fine:

```
GrizzlyHttpServer grizzlyHttpServer = new GrizzlyHttpServer(new Host("localhost", 80));
```

However, if I change it to use code from the Grizzly Jersey classpath for JAX-RS stuff:

```
        ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
        HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(
                URI.create("http://localhost:80/rest"),
                resourceConfig,
                false
        );
        grizzlyHttpServer = new GrizzlyHttpServer(httpServer, new Host("localhost", 80));
```

Then on the createHttpServer() method is aborts with

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

I don't tell it to use Spring. What magic is going on here?

Here's the full stack trace:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from class path resource
>   [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider.createXmlSpringConfiguration(SpringComponentProvider.java:164)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider.createSpringContext(SpringComponentProvider.java:155)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider.initialize(SpringComponentProvider.java:98)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:430)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:163)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:323)
>     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)  at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:320)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:285)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:331)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java:141)
>     at
>   com.optimaize.soapworks.exampleproject.server.boot.GrizzlySoapWebServer.start(GrizzlySoapWebServer.java:39)
>     at
>   com.optimaize.soapworks.exampleproject.server.boot.Boot.boot(Boot.java:38)
>     at
>   com.optimaize.soapworks.exampleproject.server.boot.Boot.main(Boot.java:18)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
>     ... 30 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User peeskillet found the answer.

I have this Maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

probably from copy-pasting dependencies from an example. I do use Spring, but I handle the DI myself. My project already has all the Spring and other dependencies.

Simply removing this dependency solves the case.

The explanation is that `new GrizzlyHttpServer()` is pure Grizzly code, while `GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer()` is code from the grizzly jersey project. So having both

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And the aforementioned `jersey-spring3` causes the behavior as described.

Comment: Having the same issue but I don't have `jersey-spring3` as a dependency. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

As one could guess, adding a dummy empty applicatonContext.xml makes the problem go away:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
</beans>
```

This is too much magic for my taste. I'll leave the question open.

Comment: _"I don't tell it to use Spring"_ - You must have `jersey-spring3`. That's the only way this would happen. If you aren't using Spring, then why do you have that dependency? :-)

Comment: I also used this "solution" but trying to avoid it. Any luck?